# Custom datePipe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create custom datePipe in angular to convert a timestamp to a date with a formate of "MMM d, y, h:mm:ss"

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";

@Pipe({name: 'timestampFormatter'})
export class TimestampFormatter implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
}

transform(value: string, format: string = 'MMM d, y, h:mm:ss a'): string {
const date = new Date(value.substring(2))
return this.datePipe.transform(date, format)}}
```

then i got this error...
[image]

and this error in my html..

[image]

Please note that date i get from response look like this **D:20240211132714**

Comment: It not recomended yo inject the `DatePipe` itself. Use the `formatDate` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need declare the component in one of your modules eg.

```
@NgModule({
declerations : [ TimestampFormatter, ...]
...})
export class YourModule{}
```

But even better you can mark the pipe as `standalone`, so you don't need to declare it.

```
@Pipe({name: 'timestampFormatter', standalone:true })
```

With the `standalone` you can just import the pipe and use it in the wanted component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it in your module just like a component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...,
    TimestampFormatter
 ],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
export class MyModule {}
```